# VGG16 Transfer learning with an additional input source

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to use Tensorflow for transfer learning using a pre-trained VGG16 model.

However, the input to the model in my problem is an RGB image with an extra channel functioning as a binary mask. This is different than the original input on which the model was trained (224x224 RGB images).

I think that using the pretrained model is still possible in this case. How do I assign weights for connections between the first convolutional layer and the extra channel? Is transfer learning still applicable in such a scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: to my knowledge, you need transform you image format to the format in the model.there are many lib support that and tensorflow also have some native api to do image preprocessing.

Comment: Thanks @scotthuang, but the image format is not the issue. The images are in the same format. The problem is that the input to my model has 4 channels and not 3 as the original input for VGG16. I need to somehow manually modify the kernel in the first conv layer to account for one extra input channel. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how this can be done.